# Java - Why does aspectj require a plugin to be installed?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

So I am trying to use AOP in my application for logging and some error handling.
Most people recommended using aspectj, so my question is why does aspectj require me to install an eclipse plugin to be able to use it?
Doesn't aspectj simply use reflection to modify classes at run-time?

We are also using a build server , do I need to install anything on the build server as well in order to run a project using aspectj?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't, unless you specifically want to have Eclipse be aspect-aware, and include AspectJ functionality in its internal build process. (IMO IDE support for AOP is awesome, and makes AOP much easier to deal with. the gutter markings alone are worth the price of admission.)

AspectJ modifies byte-code; you cannot do what it does through pure reflection,

Your build server needs the appropriate libraries. If you're doing compile-time weaving, that needs to be added to the build script.

Answer (score 2):

Aspect-J uses an agent to modify the classes by so called load-time-weaving. This is required since java-proxies can only work with interfaces. The agent augments the classes with additional (byte) code.

EDIT: Plugins usually provide additional functionality to define and review *point cuts* and *join points*.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about why there is an Eclipse plugin required.

Answer (score 1):

No, You dont require any plugin to compile/run code written using AOP.

Rather you need to add class-path information while compiling/running your application.

For example, you can take a look [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/printable.html#antTasks-install). It adds aspectj jars using ant to run the example. And it needs no plugin to run the AspectJ code for sure.

**About plugin & eclipse:** This is about giving eclipse idea to understand AspectJ code and not to confuse as invalid java code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Maven project, you just have to put some dependencies to work with Aspect.
I'm working with Netbeans and use AspectJ and it works perfectly. No plugin to install.

See : http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/ for some information.